# Does True Seeing reveal an Elder Oblex's simulacrum's true form as an ooze?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm currently playing in a campaign where we've encountered an Elder Oblex.  Before we ventured into its lair I twinned [True Seeing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing) onto myself and another party member.

Later on it was revealed that a pretty suspicious humanoid male we met down there was actually a simulacrum created by the [Elder Oblex's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/elder-oblex) *Sulfurous Impersonation* ability.

The description of the ability is:

> As a bonus action, the oblex can extrude a piece of itself that assumes the appearance of one Medium or smaller creature whose memories it has stolen. This simulacrum appears, feels, and sounds exactly like the creature it impersonates, though it smells faintly of sulfur. The oblex can impersonate 2d6 + 1 different creatures, each one tethered to its body by a strand of slime that can extend up to 120 feet away. For all practical purposes, the simulacrum is the oblex, meaning the oblex occupies its space and the simulacrum’s space simultaneously. The slimy tether is immune to damage, but it is severed if there is no opening at least 1 inch wide between the oblex’s main body and the simulacrum. The simulacrum disappears if the tether is severed.

From the description of Truesight in the Basic Rules/Player's Handbook (emphasis mine).

> A monster with truesight can, out to a specific range, see in normal and magical darkness, see invisible creatures and objects, automatically detect visual illusions and succeed on saving throws against them, **and perceive the original form of a shapechanger or a creature that is transformed by magic**.

So, while not necessarily the traditional definition of a shapechanger (typically associated with polymorph'd creatures or lycanthropes), clearly the Elder Oblex is shapechanging beyond its natural composition, and should be detectable via True Seeing, and the characters who had True Seeing active should have seen an ooze in the guise of a man.

Is this a reasonable deduction or a stretch? Perhaps there is there a more specific definition of what is or isn't a shapechanger somewhere that I am missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The Oblex's Simulacrum would not be revealed**

The text you quoted from True Seeing describes all of the possible things it reveals:

> A monster with truesight can, out to a specific range, see in normal and magical darkness, see invisible creatures and objects, automatically detect visual illusions and succeed on saving throws against them, and perceive the original form of a shapechanger or a creature that is transformed by magic.

Let's take each of these one-by-one. Obviously, the Oblex's ability is not normal or magical darkness, or an invisible creature or object, so I will skip those.

**detect visual illusions and succeed on saving throws against them**

> the oblex can extrude a piece of itself that assumes the appearance of one Medium or smaller creature whose memories it has stolen.

Since a part of the oblex is taking the form of the creature and the ability states that this duplicate 'appears, feels, and sounds exactly like the creature it impersonates', this is not a visual illusion at work.

**perceive the original form of a shapechanger**

Shapechanger is a particular creature subtype (officially called a creature Tag, MM pg. 7), denoted in parenthesis after any other creature types, found on creatures such as Wererats, Wereboars, Succubi, Mimics, Imps, and Vampires.  The Oblex only has the Ooze type, so is not officially a shapechanger.

**or a creature that is transformed by magic**

While this ability may *feel* magical, it is not. According to the Sage Advice Compendium, you can determine if an ability is magical by asking the following questions:

- Is it a magic item? *no, the oblex is a creature*
- Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell
  that’s mentioned in its description? *no, it does not name any spells, despite the similarities*
- Is it a spell attack? *no, it is an ability*
- Is it fueled by the use of spell slots? *nope, again*
- Does its description say it’s magical? *This would be the one most likely to give our Oblex away; unfortunately, the description of the ability does not say it is magical.*

Your best bet to spotting the Oblex is to spot the slimy tether running between the Oblex and its simulacrum, or notice the smell of sulfur that the simulacrum gives off; they are crafty oozes.

Comment: This is a very thorough analysis. Excellent work.

Comment: @NautArch thank you for pointing out that question. I do think there's some ambiguity in the wording of the Find Familiar spell which this answer does not fully address; If I can find a better source to back up my opinion that the spirit is not magically transformed by the spell to take the animal's form, then I will most certainly post to that question.

Comment: Thank you .. nailed it and actually this answer can be used to answer many other questions about magic...

Comment: Indeed, I have to agree with the other commenters here.  It's a great answer.  Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: @Yvihs You're welcome; glad I could help! Happy gaming!